# Laravel 5.4 Query Builder - Where condition with 2 table fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I'm trying to use a query on selecting `products` that are on **Critical Level**. So basically, if the product's `quantity` is lower than its `reorder_point`, it'll be considered as **Critical**.

Here's my `query` that I'm using:

```
$products = DB::table('inventory')
            ->where('quantity', '<=', 'reorder_point')
            ->orderBy('quantity', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

But it only shows once the `quantity` of that row is set to `0` or less. So I'm asumming that the value of `re_orderpoint` in the where condition is `0`.

But everything works when I use this query in `phpMyAdmin`:

`SELECT * from inventory where quantity <= reorder_point`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel gives you `whereColumn` for comparing columns of same table. You can do it like this:

```
$products = DB::table('inventory')
        ->whereColumn('quantity', '<=', 'reorder_point')
        ->orderBy('quantity', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

See docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses).
Hope you understand.

Comment: Damn! This is spot on brother! Hahaha. Thanks, this did the trick. :)
I forgot to check the different `where` types of `Query Builder.`

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Really ? Congrats Man. :D